# AJAX запрос на текущую страницу PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, request, page

Я использую JQuery. В общем текущая php страница выводит html код с помощью echo. На кнопку у меня стоит событие клик и выполняется ajax запрос.
PHP

```
...
циклы и вывод html code
...
if (...) {
  echo 'html code';
} else if (...) {
  echo 'html code';
}
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '',
        data: {
          text: 'Hello!'
        },
        success: (response)=>{
            console.log('Запрос успешно отправился, получаем ответ', response);
        }
    });
```

Я пытаюсь отловить запрос с помощью

```
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
  echo 'Я получил запрос '.$_POST['text'];
}
```

Но вместо ответа я получаю html код всей страницы. Мне очень важно выполнить запрос в этом же файле т.к хранятся все нужны данные для обработки.

Comment: POST никогда не отдаст всю страницу. Проблема у адмиНа

Answer (score 2):

Сервер формирует html по вашим указаниям и его выводит. Вам нужно вывести только нужные данные и закончить вывод на этом.

То есть, например:

```
<?php
// до всякого вывода проверяем:
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
  echo 'Я получил запрос '.$_POST['text'];
  die();
} 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
... 
Ну и тут уже html вашей страницы
```